# Node.js in Webpack, what is role?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I just have faced with Webpack and try to understand.

Webpack - it is bundler for all front-end files in project. So? What is role of Node.js for Webpack, why it is necessary and what is an alternative to Node.js in Webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack is written in JavaScript, NodeJS is the Javascript runtime it runs on. As for alternatives - probably none.

Comment: thank you very much. Excuce me for second quiestion, but big flow of information. Did I understand correctly - it is possible include in html-file Babel as standalone package, and it will perform functions of the NodeJS, but for Webpack is necessary Node? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, Babel seems to have a browser-only implementation (babel-standalone), but Webpack doesn't, which makes sense as Webpack has different goals and a bigger scope.